# jmeter, how to set "think times" in one go?

Tags: jmeter

When you use the recording controller, you end up with say 30 pages as 30 transaction controllers, each controller with say 20 requests.

If you want a standard pause (think time) between pages, you can use the "add think times to children"

this adds a "flow control action" after each page/transaction controller.

To set the "duration" value to "${thinkTime}, where thinkTime is defined in the "Dedfined Variables" controller, I have to edit and save each one.

Is there any way to edit or set them once?

I tried adding a single constant timer to the "recording controller", but this puts the pause between every request, not every page.

You can ctrl-select all the "think time" objects, but if you then edit and save, it only saves one.

Adding think times between pages is something I do so often, I am sure there must be a way to not have to edit each one if they should all be the same?

Answer (score 1):

If you're an "optimisation freak" consider using "Recording with Think Time" [JMeter Template](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-save-%E2%80%98loads%E2%80%99-time-using-jmeters-template-feature) which automatically adds an [Uniform Random Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Uniform_Random_Timer) with the relevant value placeholder:

[image]

If you don't link the Uniform Random Timer you can replace it with i.e. [Flow Control Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) sampler and make your own brand new template.